# Is there a popular config for Neovim?

Tags: vimrc, neovim, lua, init, init.lua

I found a lot of repositories in Github about `init.vim` like
[amix vimrc](https://github.com/amix/vimrc) but I couldn't find anything about `init.lua`.
Do you know some repository? I think many of people still using Vim.

Comment: This is really not the point of using vim. If you are not capable of self help to read docs and configure yourself you're better off with any other editor. Using any prepackaged config will only delay issues and when they appear you won't have a clue. Neither will you be able to get support from anybody except the distributor of that config.

Comment: I just want to read them as a sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of Vim "distributions" here are some popular ones:

- [Amix](https://github.com/amix/vimrc)
- [SpaceVim](https://github.com/SpaceVim/SpaceVim)
- [Spf13](https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim)

There are also a number of Neovim "distributions" here are some popular ones:

- [SpaceVim](https://github.com/SpaceVim/SpaceVim)
- [NvChad](https://nvchad.com/)
- [LunarVim](https://www.lunarvim.org/)
- [KickStart](https://github.com/nvim-lua/kickstart.nvim)
- [LazyVim](https://www.lazyvim.org/)

Remark: [SpaceVim](https://github.com/SpaceVim/SpaceVim) supports both Vim and Neovim.

Remark: Since most Vim plugins are Neovim compatible it should be possible to adapt a Vim distribution to a Neovim distribution but not all project support that explicitly.

Comment: what is the difference between `vim config` and `vim distribution` ?

Comment: Config is probably a better word. I use distribution in the sense of Linux distribution the block are the same: Vim, plugins but they are preorganized for you and some extra is provided to let you configure further. Not everyone use these distributions a fair number of users built they own config.

Comment: do you use one of them personally?

Comment: I spent most of my time with gVim. But I have installed NvChad, LunarVim and LazyVim to give support. They look great but you have to learn the way to configure them (they have their own way each). I suppose it is a good option for someone that would like to have an idea of what he could get without spending time selecting plugins and tweaking his configuration.